# Обрезка строки с mb_strpos до определенного символа

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть например: `http://test.ru/`

Нужно обрезать слэш именно после `.ru/`

Есть вариант: `$cut = mb_strpos($text, '/');`

Но в таком варианте обрезается : **/**/ то есть первый слеш после http:

Как быть? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `rtrim($text, '/');`, а лучше читайте: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Что значит не работает? Функция rtrim() дана для конкретного примера, ссылка дана для решения задачи для любого url на входе.

Comment: @Вебмастер вы почитайте мануал...вам не зря ссылку на него дали..... rtrim не просто удаляет пробелы в конце строки

Comment: Значит не так............http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34ef821878d815fce24aaef074998aed0cf4432e

Comment: @Вебмастер вас не смущает, что имя параметра в функции (и далее её использование в mb_substr и if) и имя, куда складывается результат функции `rtrim($text, '/');` одинаковые?

Answer (score 1):

Rtrim работает не только с пробелами - эта функция удаляет заданные символы из конца строки:

```
$url = 'http://test.ru/';

var_dump (rtrim ($url, '/'));
```

Пример: 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7389331b0758d7447a7ff64e1312259b1f4c7447